# how to redirect page if parameter set?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

hey i want to make a thing but i need some help.

ive got an index.php with codes. and i added "file" parameter to index.php. so i mean if "index.php?file=/folder/folder/picture.png" is set, go to file. if "file=" not set do not do anything.

I get "file" parameter with $_REQUEST thingy. please help thanks..

Comment: What's the problem?  Sounds like you've got most of the logic worked out.

Comment: I don't know how to let it go to file if "file" paramt set.

Comment: Can you define: *go to file*?

Comment: if domain.com/index.php?file=/a/a/a.png set then go to domain.com/a/a/a.png

Comment: Please don't open new identical questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529816/how-to-redirect-page-if-parameter-set

Comment: @Ronnie: Don't use the back button to edit your question, use the "edit" link just below the question's text. (I have already edited to include the changes you made, and the duplicate has already been closed.)

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit unclear, but something like this should be what you're looking for:

```
if(isset($_GET['file'])) {
    header('Content-disposition: attachment');
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    readfile($_GET['file']);
    exit();
}
```

That would "redirect to file" if the file parameter is set.

Note that this poses a *HUGE* security hole as users can download any file from your server, but this should give you some pointers at least.